# Using variables outside a definition loop, when defined inside one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a task in which I need to use a variable that is defined in a definition function, outside of the definition loop, the code is:

```
def startmenu(): #this is to call back here at any time
    startmenuoption = 1
    while startmenuoption == 1:
        startoption = input("Would you like to create, check or quit?")
        if startoption in ["Check", "check"]:
            print("You chose check!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        elif startoption in ["Create", "create"]:
            print("You chose create!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        elif startoption in ["Quit", "quit"]:
            print("You quit!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        else:
            print("Invalid reason try again!")

startmenu()
if startoption in ["Check"]:
    print("Checking!")
else:
    print("Okay!")
```

I know it seems like a simple option to remove the definition loop, but that's what I'm trying to avoid as its what i need it for.

Comment: The way to do this is by passing and returning values from your function

Comment: what's the purpose of the code beneath your function call? it looks like it's doing the same thing as within the function itself

Comment: `return startoption` at the end of your function. Then, when calling your function do it like `startoption = startmenu()`. These are the minimum (not the best) changes to what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `if..else` part to method.

```
def startmenu():#this is to call back here at any time
    startmenuoption = 1
    while startmenuoption == 1:
        startoption = raw_input("Would you like to create, check or quit?")
        if startoption in ["Check","check"]:
            print("You chose check!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        elif startoption in ["Create","create"]:
            print("You chose create!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        elif startoption in ["Quit","quit"]:
            print("You quit!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        else:
            print("Invalid reason try again!")

    if startoption in ["Check"]:
        print("Checking!")
    else:
        print("Okay!")
startmenu()
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the variables inside function, you can do it like this :

```
def fun():
    fun.x=1

fun()
print(fun.x)                   #will print 1
```

Or just use `global variable`, which you can access and modify in your function using `global`.

```
x=None

def fun():
    global x
    x=1

fun()
print(x)                       #will print 1
```

**Note : I would suggest using** `global` **instead of the first method.**

Comment: I'd delete the first part :)

Comment: Just suggesting. I know its bit unusual to be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions to this. You could pass this as a parameter into your function and define it before you call startmenu() something like:

startoption = None
startmenu(startoption)

you could also return the value

ans = startmenu()
in startmenu return startoption

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to return the value when you call the function like so:

```
def startmenu(): #this is to call back here at any time
    startmenuoption = 1
    while startmenuoption == 1:
        startoption = input("Would you like to create, check or quit?")
        if startoption in ["Check", "check"]:
            print("You chose check!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        elif startoption in ["Create", "create"]:
            print("You chose create!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        elif startoption in ["Quit", "quit"]:
            print("You quit!")
            startmenuoption = 0
        else:
            print("Invalid reason try again!")
    return startoption

startoption = startmenu()
if startoption in ["Check"]:
    print("Checking!")
else:
    print("Okay!")
```

Comment: `startoption = str`?